# Image Rotation Java

Tags: java, image, rotation

I found a method to rotate an image in java.

```
public static BufferedImage rotate(BufferedImage image, double angle)
    {
        double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle)), cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle));
        int w = image.getWidth(), h = image.getHeight();
        int neww = (int) Math.floor(w * cos + h * sin), newh = (int) Math.floor(h * cos + w * sin);
        GraphicsConfiguration gc = getDefaultConfiguration();
        BufferedImage result = gc.createCompatibleImage(neww, newh, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
        Graphics2D g = result.createGraphics();
        g.translate((neww - w) / 2, (newh - h) / 2);
        g.rotate(angle, w / 2, h / 2);
        g.drawRenderedImage(image, null);
        g.dispose();
        return result;
    }
```

But there seems to be a bug on this line

```
GraphicsConfiguration gc = getDefaultConfiguration();
```

When I hover my mouse over it, it says "The method getDefaultConfiguration() is undefined for the type Player"

These are my imports

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the example you found is using it's own method to get the `GraphicsConfiguration`

You could use `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration()` instead...

Answer (score 1):

Mad Programmer's answer will fix the compilation error however the original method is incorrect (forgets to convert the angle to radians) try the below

```
public static BufferedImage rotateImage(BufferedImage src, double degrees) {
    double radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);

    int srcWidth = src.getWidth();
    int srcHeight = src.getHeight();

    double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(radians));
    double cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(radians));
    int newWidth = (int) Math.floor(srcWidth * cos + srcHeight * sin);
    int newHeight = (int) Math.floor(srcHeight * cos + srcWidth * sin);

    BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight,
        src.getType());
    Graphics2D g = result.createGraphics();
    g.translate((newWidth - srcWidth) / 2, (newHeight - srcHeight) / 2);
    g.rotate(radians, srcWidth / 2, srcHeight / 2);
    g.drawRenderedImage(src, null);

    return result;
}
```